# How to Install Flutter in Macbook M1 chip without Rosetta or Homebrew or any intel related changes as well as not to use any third party tool?

Tags: flutter, apple-m1, macos-ventura

I want to install Flutter without third party software like Rosetta, Homebrew. Reason behind that is I don't want to use that type of third party which affected to the core system of MACBOOK M1 chipset.

Comment: FYI Rosetta is not third-party software.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need Rosetta to install Flutter, but you need it to use Flutter with full functionality. You can use git(which comes with Xcode) to clone Flutter repository on your machine. Check out the official [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos).

As for the Rosetta, it is still necessary, several of the binaries shipped in the SDK are still x64, like the one that proxies iOS to macOS ports, as well as the gen_snapshot that creates the x64 macOS app release binaries on M1 so users on Intel Macs can install your app.

The most important binaries like dart, macOS and iOS simulator Flutter frameworks are running natively as arm64 though.

Comment: idevicesyslog is a legacy binary and I refuse to install Rosetta 2 because it's just bailing out lazy developers - if anybody knows how to compile this binary from source I am all ears

Comment: Wow they're using an unmaintained library in Flutter. :facepalm: